# for loop post condition and more (c programming)

Tags: c

note that i am a beginner in coding (i've been practicing c for about 2 months)

I'm writing a hangman program, I'm writing the code for the 'engine' now: unscrambling words from _ _ _, substituting letters from the user if they exist.
Here is my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char letter;
    int tries = 7;
    int position;
    int match;
    char example[100];
    gets(example);
    int wordlength = strlen(example);
    char represent = '_';
    for (int i = 0; i < wordlength; i++)
    {
        printf(" ");
        printf("%c", represent); /**loop worked properly**/
        /**not sure if i should break this loop here or merge it with the next**/
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wordlength; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &letter); /** it scans half the post condition. if wordlength=6, loop terminates after 3**/
        if (example[i] == letter) { match = 1; position = i; printf("match"); }
        else tries -= 1;
        if (match == 1) { example[position] = letter; } /**these conditions also only work for i=0; the first element.**/
    }
}
```

I have tried scanf with an integer variable; it works. I have also tried using the string terminating character as the post condition- similar effect as before.  Now please consider my inexperience when replying to this post- fairly simple answers please.

Comment: Note that `scanf` with `%c` won't skip whitespace. So if the user types `a b c` and presses enter, then you will get six characters: `a` `space` `b` `space` `c` `newline`.

Comment: To make `scanf()` skip leading whitespace use `" %c"`. Note the space before `%c`.

Comment: thank you, i tried it and it works now.

Comment: Here is my hint here. It is not any final solution, yet I would strongly suggest that you avoid gets in a C program. It's not a safe programming choice. Use fgets instead. The prototype is: char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream);
fgets(example, sizeof(example), stdin);

Comment: thank you krassi Em. I'm not sure i understand your solution however. To the best of my knowledge, fgets takes input already available from a file and uses that in source code. My intent is to take input from a user, and compare it to individual elements of a char array gotten from a file.